# multiprocessing with twisted

Tags: multithreading, twisted, multiprocessing

My twisted application receives a large number of packet and uses multiple threads to process packets. I process packets in separate threads so that the reactor loop is free to receive packets. However, because of the GIL, only 1 thread is executing in reality. As a result, the thread in which reactor loop is running falls behind and loses packets.

Instead of threads I want to use multiple processes. Can someone please guide me how I can use multiple processes with twisted?

Answer (score 3):

Use `twisted.internet.reactor.`[`spawnProcess`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.html) or [`Ampoule`](https://launchpad.net/ampoule) to start your subprocesses.  You can then receive standard output from those processes the same way you'd receive network packets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perspective broker "twisted.spread.pb" to exchange date between your multiple twistd processes or even performing remote call.